# Creating Diff's and applying Patch for apk's using bsdiff and bspatch

Tags: apk

How to create a diff file for two apk's (android packages) and patch them ?. I know that it requires diff and patch utility. But how to use it ?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you are using bsdiff tool for two APK old.apk and new.apk:

Step 1.

```
bsdiff old.apk new.apk patch.apk
```

You will get an APK named patch.apk.

Step 2.

```
bspatch old.apk new.apk patch.apk
```